# Popular Azure implementations

Tags: azure, cloud, cloud-hosting

I am planning to do a presentation on Microsoft azure, in which I would like to list out some popular applications running from windows azure. I heard like Stackoverflow was running from Microsoft Azure, I am not sure whether this is right or not.

Please help me to compile a list of popular applications running from Microsoft Azure.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @pnuts - seriously? You edited the tags on this question, from 4 years ago? A question that should simply be closed (as it's off-topic)?

Comment: @pnuts - Ok I had no idea that tag was being burninated. Carry on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty certain StackOverflow is not running on Azure - but it is running mainly on .Net. You can read about SE's infrastructure on https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/server/

The most publicised Azure uses are all promoted by Microsoft - see this pivot view - http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/evidence/

Comment: Thats what I was looking for. The list is pretty exhaustive.